# Significance of Hats?

Tags: discussion

Today, I have seen some hats on Display Picture saying some Winter's Hat.

I have not finding the utility of those because there are already many badges for that which are being used for Hats

### If there is already badges for the same purpose what are the significance of HATS

I am unable to understand the significance of hats does any one??

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/

Comment: There is a button for that.

Comment: Obviously, the key difference is that badges would look *entirely ridiculous* if you stuck them on your digital head. :P

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd there is button for what

Comment: @KeyLimePiePhotonAndroid: You can opt-out of the hats thing, preventing you from using nor seeing hats.

Answer (score 15):

### The significance of hats is that they are fun.

Comment: YEAH, THEY ARE FUN. ON A SIDE NOTE, WHY ARE WE YELLING?

Comment: BECAUSE HATS ARE SO FUN THAT YELLING IS REQUIRED

Comment: BECAUSE HATS ARE FESTIVE AND SO IS ALL-CAPS!

Comment: BUT STAK OVARFLOW HATES ANYTHING FUN?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Stack Overflow HATS; anything fun!

Answer (score 4):

### Because hats are Awesome!!

[image]

Comment: And hats combined with the brass bell of an air-powered musical instrument are even more awesome.